# Refresh dropdown content with angular5/rxjs

Tags: rxjs, angular5, observable, http-get

I tried to create dropdown which refreshed its content when it is clicked.
Below there is my solution, but I'm looking for a better way to do that.

Is it possible to not use in `MyComponent` reference to

```
@ViewChild('dropdownRef') dropdownEl: ElementRef;
```

and keep that working?
Or maybe any other ideas?

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('dropdownRef')
  dropdownEl: ElementRef;

  dropdownClicks$: Observable<any>;

  items: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(public myService: MyService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.items = this.myService.getItems();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dropdownClicks$ =
      Observable.fromEvent(this.dropdownEl.nativeElement, 'click');

    this.dropdownClicks$.subscribe(obs => this.items = this.myService.getItems() );
  }
}



export class MyService {

  url = 'http://localhost:11111/api/items';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getItems(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<any[]>(this.url);
  }
}
```

and html:

```
<div #dropdownRef class="btn nav-item dropdown" ngbDropdown>
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="id01" href="#" ngbDropdownToggle>Items</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="id01" ngbDropdownMenu>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items | async" class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{item.text}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not to use the Angular built in support for html events, something like `<div #dropdownRef class="btn nav-item dropdown" ngbDropdown (click)="getItems()"`. Then you change the way you use the async pipe like this `*ngFor="let item of getItems() | async"`. It should work and should allow you eliminate both the `dropdownRef` and `items` component's variables.

Comment: @Picci good point, but if I use `*ngFor="let item of getItems() | async"`, there are unstopable requests to a server. My test shows that `items: Observable<any[]>;` must stay, otherwise there are a lot of requests.